# Default Argument decorator python

Tags: python, decorator, signature

Python 3.6

I'm attempting to create a decorator that automatically assigns the string of the argument as the default value.

such as:

```
def example(one='one', two='two', three='three'):
    pass
```

would be equivalent to:

```
@DefaultArguments
def example(one, two, three):
    pass
```

Here is my attempt (doesn't work.. yet..) `DefaultArguments`:

```
from inspect import Parameter, Signature, signature


class DefaultArguments(object):

    @staticmethod
    def default_signature(signature):
        def default(param):
            if param.kind in (Parameter.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD, Parameter.POSITIONAL_ONLY):
                return param.replace(default=param.name)
            else:
                return param
        return Signature([default(param) for param in signature.parameters.values()])

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.sig = self.default_signature(signature(func))

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        arguments = self.sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
        return self.func(arguments)
```

The staticmethod `default_signature` creates the desired signature for the function, but I'm having difficulty assigning the new signature to the function. I'm trying to use Signature.`bind` I've read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) but i'm missing something.

**EDIT**

Incorporating Ashwini Chaudhary's answer:

```
from inspect import Parameter, Signature, signature

class DefaultArguments(object):

    @staticmethod
    def default_signature(signature):
        def default(param):
            if param.kind in (Parameter.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD, Parameter.POSITIONAL_ONLY):
                return param.replace(default=param.name)
            else:
                return param
        return Signature([default(param) for param in signature.parameters.values()])

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.sig = self.default_signature(signature(func))
        print(self.sig)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ba = self.sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
        ba.apply_defaults()
        return self.func(*ba.args, **ba.kwargs)
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing the `__defaults__` attribute?

Comment: Admittedly no, I guess  I was hoping to avoid doing it manually, and let the Signature class handle it

Comment: ["Signature objects are *immutable*."](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Signature)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After binding the args and keywords with the signature you need to call [`apply_defaults`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.BoundArguments.apply_defaults) on the [`BoundArguments`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.BoundArguments) instance to set the default values for missing arguments.

Also the function call will be invoked using `BoundArguments`'s `args` and `kwargs` properties.

```
def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ba = self.sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
    ba.apply_defaults()
    return self.func(*ba.args, **ba.kwargs)
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> @DefaultArguments
... def example(one, two, three):
...         print(one, two, three)
...

>>> example()
one two three
>>> example('spam')
spam two three
>>> example(one='spam', three='eggs')
spam two eggs
```

---

A functional version of your code that also updates the signature of the decorated function:

```
from functools import wraps
from inspect import Parameter, Signature, signature


def default_arguments(func):

    def default(param):
        if param.kind in (Parameter.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD, Parameter.POSITIONAL_ONLY):
            param = param.replace(default=param.name)
        return param

    sig = Signature([default(param) for param in signature(func).parameters.values()])

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        ba = sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
        ba.apply_defaults()
        return func(*ba.args, **ba.kwargs)

    wrapper.__signature__ = sig
    return wrapper
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> from inspect import getfullargspec    
>>> @default_arguments
... def example(one, two, three):
...         print(one, two, three)
...

>>> getfullargspec(example)
FullArgSpec(
    args=['one', 'two', 'three'],
    varargs=None,
    varkw=None,
    defaults=('one', 'two', 'three'),
    kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={}
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the functional version. That's cool, I will use that.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to work:

```
import inspect

def default_args(func):
    argspec = inspect.getfullargspec(func)

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        unpassed_positional_args = argspec.args[len(args):]
        kwargs.update((a, a) for a in unpassed_positional_args if a not in kwargs)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

It relies on the fact that you can pass positional arguments by keyword in python.  e.g. if you have a function:

```
def foo(a, b):
    ...
```

You're completely in your rights to call it as:

```
foo(b=1, a=2)
```

My solution figures out how many positional arguments you've passed and uses that to figure out which positional arguments *weren't* passed.  I then add those positional argument names to the `kwargs` dict instead.

And the cool thing here is that if someone needs this for python2.x, they only need to change `getfullargspec` to `getargspec` and it should work OK.

---

### A note on speed:

Comparing my solution with Ashwini's excellent explanation shows that the simple decorator is approximately 10x faster than messing around with Signature objects:

```
@default_args
def foo(a, b, c):
    pass

@DefaultArguments
def bar(a, b, c):
    pass

@default_arguments
def qux(a, b, c):
    pass

import timeit
print(timeit.timeit('foo()', 'from __main__ import foo'))  # 1.72s
print(timeit.timeit('bar()', 'from __main__ import bar'))  # 17.4s
print(timeit.timeit('qux()', 'from __main__ import qux'))  # 17.6
```

His solution actually updates the `__signature__` of the function (which is really nice).  In principle, you could take the `Signature` creation logic and add that to my solution to update the `__signature__` but keep the `argspec` style logic for the actual computation...

Comment: @JamesSchinner -- There was a small bug that Ashwini's test cases alerted me to -- Basically I needed to make sure that I didn't add defaults if they were already present in `kwargs`.

Comment: This is super clean. If I wasn't emotionally invested in my code. I'd use this. I selected Ashwini's because it explained what was wrong with my previous understanding.

Comment: Yeah -- I have no problem with that.  In fact, I agree with your giving him the checkmark -- His is a great answer to your question.  In a lot of ways, it's better than mine because it explains more about the API that you were asking about.   (and I think that this is a good demonstration why StackOverflow allows _multiple_ answers :-).

Comment: it seems like the 'green tick' can only be applied to one.