# Accessing keyword argument of decorated function inside the decorator fails in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-decorators, functools

`kwargs` is empty in the following code.
How to access timeout keyword arg of the decorated function?

```
import functools
def retriable(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        timeout = kwargs['timeout']
        criteria_satisfied = func(*args, **kwargs)
        while not criteria_satisfied and timeout > 0:
            time.sleep(5)
            timeout -= 5
            criteria_satisfied = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return criteria_satisfied
    return wrapper

@retriable
def decorated(ip, timeout=60):
    ... some logic
    return True 

decorated(ip)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default Argument decorator python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45873384/default-argument-decorator-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to make decorator with arguments. Which would return another decorator over the function and would populate the created closure with the argument value.

```
import functools
def retriable_with_arg(timeout):
    def retriable(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            alive_timeout = timeout
            criteria_satisfied = func(*args, **kwargs)
            while not criteria_satisfied and alive_timeout > 0:
                time.sleep(5)
                alive_timeout -= 5
                criteria_satisfied = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return criteria_satisfied
     return wrapper
return retriable

@retriable(timeout=60)
def decorated(ip, timeout=60):
    ... some logic
    return True 

decorated(ip)
```